# How to invoke root privileges from a password prompt of "Software Update" window?

Tags: password, root, upgrade, gui, su

When I try to install software updates using the "Software Update" GUI, I am asked for the root password. Although, I can 'su' in a terminal, the password is not recognized as correct in the GUI prompt. I believe this is due to the user account name being different from the root account name. How can I still use the GUI then?

Comment: What Unix/Linux flavor is this? Have you tried with your password?

Comment: My password does not work either.

Comment: It is Fedora 14 with Gnome 2.32.

Comment: Check /var/log/secure for errors.  It might tell you why it is failing.

Comment: Why was this tagged `sudo` when it mentions `su`? Either this is about `sudo` or `su` — mixing both is a sure way to get lost among wrong credentials... Please double-check you are being asked the *root* password. There's no reason for the "user account name" to play a role here. If you can `su` in a terminal, you can `su` from a graphical application running under the same user, plain and simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you need to use your own password, and be in the sudoers file.  Can you run "sudo su" form a terminal? If you can't, that would be an indicator that you're not in the sudoers file, hence the password rejection.

Make sure you're listed in /etc/sudoers, or run man sudoers if you're not sure of the syntax.

Comment: That's not how PackageKit works in Fedora.  It uses the root password.

Comment: Are you sure? I used fedora from when version 12 was release up to version 15 (so it's been a couple of years now).  I recall "yum" works that way, but I only used the GUI once. Does the GUI work differently from yum?

Comment: The graphical interface uses PackageKit, which does not use sudo in any way.  There are ways to make it authenticate as the user instead of root, but it doesn't involve sudo.